# Statistic problem to be resolved on Excel (or VBA)

Tags: probability, excel

I have a stat problem and I am not sure it can be resolved; I am not good in statistic but maybe someone can help me:

I need to create two numbers: $v_1$ and $v_2$ with Excel or VBA.
I want both numbers to be selected randomly but following the three given inputs:

1. both numbers must be between two given numbers $v_\mathrm{min}$ and $v_\mathrm{max}$
2. the average of the distribution of $v_1+v_2$ must be equal to $v_\mathrm{avg}$
3. $v_1$ > $v_2$ must be true with a given probability $p_1$

Do you know how I can manage it?

Thanks

**Edit:**

The objective of my exercise is to create a very simplified simulation of a result of a basketball game.

I estimate that both teams can only score between $50$ and $110$ points ($v_\mathrm{min} = 50, v_\mathrm{max} = 110$), and I estimate that the cumulative score of both team should be between $130$ and $190$ points ($160$ in average, $v_\mathrm{avg} = 160$).
One of the two team is theoretically stronger than the other one so I give,  before the simulation the probability of winning, let say for example 60% chance of winning for team 1, which means that $v_1$ (score of team 1) should be larger than $v_2$ (score of team 2) in 60% of the simulation.

---

Following Bernhard posts, I implemented something like this:

```
p = 0.50
r1 = random between {1,2}
r2 = ramdom between [0,1]

if r1 = 1
   if r2 <= p
      v1 = truncate (random between [80.5,110])
   if r2 > p
      v1 = truncate (random between [50,80.5])
v2 = truncate (random between [Max(50,130 - v1), Min[110,190-v1)]

if r1 = 2
   if r2 <= 1- p
      v2 = truncate (random between [80.5,110])
   if r2 > 1- p
      v2 = truncate (random between [50,80.5])
v1 = truncate (random between [Max(50,130 - v2), Min[110,190-v2)]
```

The previous algorithm means:

```
        1 /  I choose randomly to calculate firstly v1 or v2 number

        2/  I select another random number: 
    if it is below the value of the 
    given probability p (or 1-p if I calculate v2 number first) then 
    the number is calculated randomly between 80.5 and 110
    otherwise calculated randomly between 50 and 80.5 
    ("a team can score between 50 and 110 points")

        3/ I calculate randomly the value of the other number 
according to the value of the first number
    taking into account that:
        -  it can only be between 50 and 110 
    ("a team can score between 50 and 110 points")
        - the sum of the two numbers is necessarly between 130 and 190 
    ("the cumulated score of both teams can be between 130 and 190")
```

With a VBA loop I simulated the code on 1,000,000 cases

When I select a probability `p = 0.50` it works well, I got a result of team1 winning of 50.01% and an average cumulated score of 160.07 (removing cases where the calculation finishes with v1 = v2)

But when I select a probability `p = 0.55` (which means theorically team 1 should win 55% of the 1,000,000 cases), I don't have a good result. Team 1 is winning effectively only 53.53%. The average cumulated score, however, remains ok : 160.06 
Even worse than this: when I select a probability `p = 0.0723` (which means theorically team 1 should win 7.23% of the 1,000,000 cases), Team 1 is winning effectively more than 19%...

Do you know what is wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Since this problem is hugely underdetermined--there are more ways to solve it than anybody could possibly describe comprehensively--could you edit this post to provide more information about why you need this and what you're trying ultimately to achieve?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: In addition, are you asking about how this is done from the point of view of understanding the problem, or are you asking for help w/ how to get Excel to do this? (Note that the latter is off topic here, but may be on topic on [SO].)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a personnal project not for study. And yes, I need a practical solution on Excel, but if I can understand theorically the answer I am implementing that's not bad neither :)

Comment: Please don't use Excel for this, the pseudo random generator it uses [does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893769/3986320)

Answer (score 1):

Excel has a function RANDBETWEEN which gives you a random number between a lower and an upper limit.

As $v_{avg}$ is given, you only need a random number $v_1$. $v_2$ can then be computed as $v_2 = v_{avg} - v_1$ to fullfill number 2. If both numbers need to be randomly selcted you could compute `v_2 = RANDBETWEEN(v_avg-v_1-1,v_avg-v_1+1)` or something similar to fulfill number 2.

For $v_1$ to be larger then $v_2$ it should to be in between $v_{avg}$ and $v_{avg}/2$. So these are the natural parameters for the RANDBETWEEN function. So far there seems to be no need for VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

But I realise now that I was not very clear on the second input, sorry for this.
I was talking about the average of the distribution of v_1 + v_2. Like  for example the normal distribution  is defined by an average value. On one draw, v_1 + v_2 can be different from v_avg.

Comment: That should be taken care of with my second alternative `v_2 = RANDBETWEEN(v_avg-v_1 - const, v_avg-v_1 + const)` where $v_2$  is drawn randomly from a distribution that is symmetric around $v_{avg}-v_1$. This way, $v_2$ is a random variable and the expected average is the expected average. I used `1` for the constant `const`which is not necessarily suitable for your range of values. You'll need to adjust that.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea. It works for the two first inputs, but doesn't take into account the last input. How can I use the probability factor inside it?

Comment: Ok this can be addressed when choosing $v_1$. Let $p_1$ be the cell with the probability between `0` and `1`. Something along the lines of $V_1$ `=IF(RAND() < p_1; RANDBETWEEN(v_avg/2, v_avg); RANDBETWEEN(0, v_avg/2)` I did not test this code, but dependend on whether a random variable ist larger or smaller then $p_1$ you choose $v_1$ as the larger or the smaller of the two random variables.